# Display Icon each second (Countdown timer)

Tags: c#, timer

I am trying to display a sort of countdown timer on my form. My program basically captures a snapshot (Via webcam) of a user once certain conditions are met. Once the conditions have been met, I want to display a countdown timer ideally picture-based (By enabling icons I have on a form) and then capture the webcam image.

So far I have been trying to use a timer and so on each tick it displays one of the icons, a tick later displays the next.. etc then captures the image. So far I can only get it to display one icon and take an image, i'm not sure how to get the icons to change on each tick for x seconds

e.g.

```
public void matchconditionshere()
   // match conditions here
   timer1.Start()

public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   _3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
   _2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
   _1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed

    // not sure what to put here to generate another tick?

   _2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
   _3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
   _1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed

   _1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
   _3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
   _2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed

   _capture.Start() 
   // capture image from webcam
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you want to use icons, it seems you need to add logic there so that you can correctly choose which icons to display. For example, for a 3-second countdown, you'd have to add code to know that for the first tick there're 3 seconds left (so that you show the 3-second icon), for the second tick there're 2 seconds left, and so on.

In other words, something like:

```
// only example value; get a real one from another input/event handler
private int _countDownSeconds = 3;
public void webCamTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (_countDownSeconds--) {
        case 3:
            // show icon for 3 and return
            break;
        case 2:
            // show icon for 2 and return
            break;
        case 1:
            // show icon for 1 and return
            break;
        case 0:
            // time to take picture
            _webCam.TakeSnapshot();
            break;
        default:
            // log a message, ask user to re-enter time limit,
            // or simply re-assign a previously entered value;
            // for example:
            _countDownSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(userTimeLimitTextBox.Text);
            break;
    }
}
```

It might be worth considering that this is likely more time-consuming to test/maintain, especially if/when the countdown timer needs to be updated (e.g. updating it to 5 seconds instead of 3, or letting it be user-configurable, etc.). Also, the higher the countdown timer goes, the greater the number of permutations you'll need to account for. You can already see the number of cases you have for a simple 3-second timer.

Perhaps displaying the countdown as a `string` representation of the numbers (e.g. `ToString()` method) would be a better idea for the long-term.

**PS:** You should also use .NET naming conventions. You can check the MSDN docs for more information on these, but in general, just look at the naming patterns already available in the .NET classes/methods/properties you're using.

Comment: Hi ray, I tried your solution and it worked a treat. Many thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define counter and count timer ticks. Use tick counter in `switch` to define at which moment what to do:

```
int _counter;

void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _counter++;
    switch(_counter)
    {
        case 1:
            _1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ...
            break;
        case 10: // do something at 10th tick
            _2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ...
            break;
        ...
    }

    // capture image from webcam
    _capture.Start() 
}
```

Comment: Also, I think `_counter=0;` should be added when the conditions met function is called. Else it will keep increasing and never evaluate to one of the switch cases. It will do it just the first time.

Answer (score 0):

From the question and sample you have posted I understand that for every tick you want to show one pic from the list of 3. This can be achieved as follows:

```
static int count=1;
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(count==1)
   {
      _1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      _2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      _3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      count++;
   }
   else if(count==2)
   {
      _2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      _1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      _3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      count++;
   }
   else
   {
      _3.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
      _1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      _3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
      count==1;
      _capture.Start() 
   }
}
```

Inside the **_capture.Start()** method make sure you stop the timer. Else timer would keep on running making multiple calls to the method.